# Using SQL Server Analysis Services with Sybase Advantage Database Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, ssas, advantage-database-server

Is it possible to use SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services with data stored in Sybase Advantage Database Server?  Either directly, or via SQL Server Integration Services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as drivers exist (and I believe they do) to connect to the database for Sybase using either oledb or .net drivers then you should be able to use the data in SSAS.  If you are having issues, you can always use SSIS to move the data into a dimensional model on a Sql Server database, but it would use the same drivers.  So it depends upon the format of the data in Sybase.  If it is in a Dimensional Model on Sybase, and the drivers exist, you can leave it there.

Comment: Thanks -- you're absolutely right, there is an Advantage OLE DB Provider, and this is working fine with SSAS.